# cannot deploy VM on google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, gcloud

I cannot deploy a VM in Google, even with marketplace I tried with different account but I'm getting same error every time I want to deploy plesk on any of, centos or ubuntu plus even I change region I get same error please help me guys.

```
plsk-ubun-hst-gcp-m has resource warnings

astronaut-ge-vm: {
 "ResourceType":"compute.v1.instance",
  "ResourceErrorCode":"400",
  "ResourceErrorMessage": {
    "code":400,
    "errors":[
      {
        "domain":"global",
        "message":"Invalid value for field 'resource.disks[0].initializeParams.sourceImage': 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/plesk-public/global/images/plesk-17-8-webhost-ubuntu-16-v20190905'. The referenced image resource cannot be found.",
        "reason":"invalid"
      }
    ],
    "message":"Invalid value for field 'resource.disks[0].initializeParams.sourceImage': 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/plesk-public/global/images/plesk-17-8-webhost-ubuntu-16-v20190905'. The referenced image resource cannot be found.",
    "statusMessage":"Bad Request",
    "requestPath":"https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/astronaut-georgia/zones/europe-west3-a/instances",
    "httpMethod":"POST"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate in more detail on what you are trying to achieve?  I am getting the impression that you are trying to deploy a custom image that you may have uploaded.  What kind of image are you trying to create the VM instance from?  Can you detail exactly the steps you are performing?

Comment: i'm creating plesk web host edition with license on ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. I guess that the marketplace deployment is not up to date. You have to open a case to Plesk for solving this. Or to install it manually on your own VM.